# iccube DEFAULT time dimension vs NON-DEFAULT

Tags: mdx, iccube

What are the differences between a DEFAULT time dimension and another time dimension ?
Is it just like for the default measure, i.e. used if no measure is mentionned in a MDX?

Can we do exactly the same things with a non-default time dimension ?

I'm thinking about Evolutions, running sums, avg, dtXXX functions, ytd function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DEFAULT time dimension is the one that is going to be used in custom rollup aggregation ([www](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/facts_aggregation.php)) when you do not define any hierarchy and a few MDX time functions when no hierarchy is defined ([Ytd](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Ytd.php), [Qtd](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Qtd.php), [Mtd](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Mtd.php), [Wtd](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Wtd.php) ...).

Apart from that there is no difference with a regular time dimension.